# sed: bad option in substitution expression

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am trying to change in a file like some data using `sed` . my file data is like this

```
variable "azure_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "AZ-EU-Spoke1-GW"
      cidr       = "2.2.2.2"
      active_mesh  = true
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "AZ-EU-Spoke2-GW"
      cidr       = "2.2.2.2" 
      active_mesh  = true
    }
  }
}
```

**and command I am using is**

```
sed -i "s/spoke1 = [{]/,/[}]/       { s/active_mesh = true/active_mesh = false/; }/g" /variables.tf
```

and I am getting error

```
sed: bad option in substitution expression
```

Comment: Typo: You have an extra `s` before the `/start/,/end/` range.

Comment: @Barmar  I didn't get exactly which `s`  you are saying

Comment: Just get rid of the `s` in `s/spoke1 = [{]/,/[}]/`

Comment: @Barmar now saying    `sed: unmatched '/'  `

Comment: Since you want to match `active_mesh  = true`, which has two spaces before the `=`, you may want `{ s/active_mesh\s\+=\s\+true/active_mesh = false/g }`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick   if I got 4 spaces I have to denote like this   `\s\\s\\s\\s\\s\` ?

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz `\s\+` will match 1 or more spaces.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  `cidr` case is not working :(  there are seven spaces . How I can tackle that. please guide

Comment: It's good that you have most of it working. Now that the problem has shifted from sed syntax errors to trying to match more complex patterns, I think it would be better and clearer if you ask a new, separate  question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  I can't post next question before 90 mins :(

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output so we can help you with that mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't have `s` before the regular expressions specifying the range of lines to process.
2. The `g` modifier should be part of the `s///` command that replaces the line, not after the `}`.
3. The pattern `/active_mesh = true/` doesn't match because it only has 1 space before `=`, but the file has 2 spaces there. You can use `/active_mesh *= *true/` to match any number of spaces around the `=`.

```
sed -i "/spoke1 = [{]/,/[}]/ { s/active_mesh *= *true/active_mesh = false/g; }" /variables.tf
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir , No error but its not changing required data :(

Comment: You have 2 spaces before `=` in the file, but only 1 space in the `s///` pattern.

Comment: ` *= *`  this is not working in case of   `cidr`  there are 7 spaces before `=`  . should not this handle all 7 spaces ?

Comment: Are you sure they're all spaces? It might be a TAB character.

Comment: I checked here  by pasting code here .  [link] (https://www.charactercountonline.com/)   . it saying  10 spaces after word

Comment: When you copy from the terminal, tabs might be converted to spaces. You need to look at the file with a hex dump.

Comment: 20202020202020202020  getting spaces in converter

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '/spoke1/{f=1} f && /active_mesh/{sub(/true/,"false")} /}/{f=0} 1' file
variable "azure_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "AZ-EU-Spoke1-GW"
      cidr       = "2.2.2.2"
      active_mesh  = false
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "AZ-EU-Spoke2-GW"
      cidr       = "2.2.2.2"
      active_mesh  = true
    }
  }
}
```

If so, GNU awk has `-i inplace` just like GNU sed has `-i` if you want to update the original file, or just do `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: if any other attribute need to change then what will be command ? I need to change f ?

Comment: `f` is just a variable being set to 1 (to represent `true` when used in a condition context) when you've **f**ound the block of text you're interested in, i.e. that within `spoke1...}`. I'd need to see what other attribute you're referring to and what you want to change it to to be able to answer. You should accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new followup question.

Comment: Sir working perfect , but there is a issue , I want to run `awk` two to three time but changes reflect of last awk run.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking followup questions of the person whose answer you accepted and so are presumably using?

Comment: Sir , I tried that but on a point that is not working properly . I tried this and worked file but I want to change 3,4 things while only last command changes are showing in file

Comment: If the answer you accepted doesn't work for you then why accept it? If it does do what you asked about but you can't enhance it to do something else then just ask a new question. Actually, no matter which answer you accept here you should ask a new question so you can show us the sample input, expected output, etc. related to your current issue.